# How to use millis on traffic light controller in Arduino

Tags: arduino, delay

I'm doing a smart city project with my Arduino and I have a question. I have created 2 functions and one of them is the traffic light controller and I use the `delay()` to make them have the right delays between them. But I have a problem. I call both of the functions inside `loop()`, but one of them only runs when the other is finished. Is there any way to run them both? I've seen people using `millis()`.

My code:

```cpp
int smartled1 = 13;
int smartled2 = 12;
int smartled3 = 11;
int smartled4 = 10;
int smartled5 = 9;
int smartled6 = 8;
int smartled7 = 7;
int smartled8 = 6;
int smartled9 = 50;
int smartled10 = 51;
int smartled11 = 52;
int smartled12 = 53;// Pin para ligar o led
int sensorPin = A0; // Seleção do pin de entrada do LDR
int sensorValor = 0; // Variavel de armazenamento do LDR inicializada a 0
int semaforo1[]= {22, 24, 26};
int semaforo2[]= {5, 4, 3};
int semaforo3[]= {29, 31, 33};
int semaforo4[]= {28, 30, 32};
int Delayvermelho = 5000;
int Delayamarelo = 2000;

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600); // Define a porta serie para comunicação
pinMode(smartled1, OUTPUT);
pinMode(smartled2, OUTPUT);
pinMode(smartled3, OUTPUT);
pinMode(smartled4, OUTPUT);
pinMode(smartled5, OUTPUT);
pinMode(smartled6, OUTPUT);
pinMode(smartled7, OUTPUT);
pinMode(smartled8, OUTPUT);
pinMode(smartled9, OUTPUT);
pinMode(smartled10, OUTPUT);
pinMode(smartled11, OUTPUT);
pinMode(smartled12, OUTPUT);// Define o pin do Led como saída
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {    
    pinMode(semaforo1[i], OUTPUT);
    pinMode(semaforo2[i], OUTPUT);
    pinMode(semaforo3[i], OUTPUT);
    pinMode(semaforo4[i], OUTPUT);
  }
}

void loop() {
    smart_lights();

  semaforos_cruzamento();
}

void semaforos_cruzamento(){
  // Making Green  LED at signal 1 and red LED's at other signal HIGH
  digitalWrite(semaforo1[2], HIGH);
  digitalWrite(semaforo1[0], LOW);
  digitalWrite(semaforo2[0], HIGH);
  digitalWrite(semaforo3[0], HIGH);
  digitalWrite(semaforo4[0], HIGH);
  delay(Delayvermelho);
  // Making Green LED at signal 1 LOW and making yellow LED at signal 1 HIGH for 2 seconds

  digitalWrite(semaforo1[1], HIGH);
  digitalWrite(semaforo1[2], LOW);
  delay(Delayamarelo);
  digitalWrite(semaforo1[1], LOW);
  // Making Green  LED at signal 2 and red LED's at other signal HIGH
  digitalWrite(semaforo1[0], HIGH);
  digitalWrite(semaforo2[2], HIGH);
  digitalWrite(semaforo2[0], LOW);
  digitalWrite(semaforo3[0], HIGH);
  digitalWrite(semaforo4[0], HIGH);
  delay(Delayvermelho);
  // Making Green LED at signal 2 LOW and making yellow LED at signal 2 HIGH for 2 seconds
  digitalWrite(semaforo2[1], HIGH);
  digitalWrite(semaforo2[2], LOW);
  delay(Delayamarelo);
  digitalWrite(semaforo2[1], LOW);
  // Making Green  LED at signal 3 and red LED's at other signal HIGH
  digitalWrite(semaforo1[0], HIGH);
  digitalWrite(semaforo2[0], HIGH);
  digitalWrite(semaforo3[2], HIGH);
  digitalWrite(semaforo3[0], LOW);
  digitalWrite(semaforo4[0], HIGH);
  delay(Delayvermelho);
  // Making Green LED at signal 3 LOW and making yellow LED at signal 3 HIGH for 2 seconds
  digitalWrite(semaforo3[1], HIGH);
  digitalWrite(semaforo3[2], LOW);
  delay(Delayamarelo);
  digitalWrite(semaforo3[1], LOW);
  // Making Green  LED at signal 4 and red LED's at other signal HIGH
  digitalWrite(semaforo1[0], HIGH);
  digitalWrite(semaforo2[0], HIGH);
  digitalWrite(semaforo3[0], HIGH);
  digitalWrite(semaforo4[2], HIGH);
  digitalWrite(semaforo4[0], LOW);
  delay(Delayvermelho);
  // Making Green LED at signal 4 LOW and making yellow LED at signal 4 HIGH for 2 seconds
  digitalWrite(semaforo4[1], HIGH);
  digitalWrite(semaforo4[2], LOW);
  delay(Delayamarelo);
  digitalWrite(semaforo4[1], LOW);


  }

void smart_lights(){  
  int sensorValor = analogRead(sensorPin);// Lê o valor fornecido pelo LDR
Serial.println(sensorValor);//Imprime os valores provenientes do sensor na ecrã
// Caso o valor lido na porta analógica A5 seja maior do que
// 800, acende o LED
// Ajuste o valor abaixo de acordo com o circuito
if (sensorValor < 400)
{
digitalWrite(smartled1, HIGH);
digitalWrite(smartled2, HIGH);  
digitalWrite(smartled3, HIGH);  
digitalWrite(smartled4, HIGH);  
digitalWrite(smartled5, HIGH);  
digitalWrite(smartled6, HIGH);  
digitalWrite(smartled7, HIGH);  
digitalWrite(smartled8, HIGH);  
digitalWrite(smartled9, HIGH);  
digitalWrite(smartled10, HIGH);  
digitalWrite(smartled11, HIGH);  
digitalWrite(smartled12, HIGH);  
}
else //Caso contrário, apaga o led
{
digitalWrite(smartled1, LOW);
digitalWrite(smartled2, LOW);  
digitalWrite(smartled3, LOW);  
digitalWrite(smartled4, LOW);  
digitalWrite(smartled5, LOW);  
digitalWrite(smartled6, LOW);  
digitalWrite(smartled7, LOW);  
digitalWrite(smartled8, LOW);  
digitalWrite(smartled9, LOW);  
digitalWrite(smartled10, LOW);  
digitalWrite(smartled11, LOW);  
digitalWrite(smartled12, LOW); 
}
}
```

Comment: Delays are blocking.  Research how to use nonblocking methods.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use state machines.

Example:

```
// totally randon delays. Prime to each other.
static const unsigned char MY_EVENT_TIMEOUT = 100;    // in milliseconds.
static const unsigned int  HIS_EVENT_TIMEOUT = 2533;   // in milliseconds.

// setup two sta=te machines.  In this example both state machines will simply 
// wait a bit before toggling between two states.

// state machines consist of different state values, a state variable, and some data

enum MyEventState {
    my_event_state_initial,    // we'll just start timing
    my_event_state_1,
    my_event_state_2,
    /* and so on... */
};

MyEventState my_state = my_state_initial;
unsigned char my_event_timestamp;   // largest my_event delay is less than 255 ms

// second state machine.
enum HisEventState {
    his_event_state_iinitial,       // we'll wait for some external event
    his_event_state_1,
    his_event_state_2,
    /* more states if you need  */
};

HisEventState his_state = his_state_initial;
unsigned int his_event_timestamp;  // largest his_event delay is less than 65535 ms

 void my_event_handler()
 {
     switch (my_state)
     {
     case my_event_state_initial:
         // initialize our timestamp and go straight to state 1
         my_event_timestamp = (unsigned char)millis();
         my_state = my_event_state_1;

        // passing though to execute next state handler immediately

     case my_event_state_1:
         // in real application, you'd likely CHECK for a triggering event first
         // and check millis() for timeouts, etc.  Using different states to 
         // check for time out...   Note the use of subtraction of UNSIGNED
         // values to avoid rollover issues altogether

         // the extra cast is the correct way to to it.  C++ subtraction MAY 
         // return an unsigned int, according to the standard.  In practice, it 
         // does not happens for 8 and 16-bit MCUs.

         // no matter what you do, do not wait, poll your input line, or 
         // check if there are bytes on the serial buffer, do not block.

         if ((unsigned char)((unsigned char)millis() - my_event_timestamp) < MY_EVENT_TIMEOUT)
         {
             // not enough time has elapsed, nothing to do, so return
             return;
         }

         my_event_timestamp = (unsigned char)millis();  // get a time stamp
         my_state = my_event_state_2;                   // change state

        // passing though to execute next state handler immediately

     case my_event_state_2: 
         // it's always the same logic in this simple state machine, 
         // but you can put any logic you want here to turn one light on or off,
         // check inputs, etc..
         if ((unsigned char)millis() - my_event_timestamp < MY_EVENT_TIMEOUT)
         {
             // not enough time has elapsed, nothing to do, so return
             return;
         }

         my_event_timestamp = (unsigned char)millis();  // get a time stamp
         my_state = my_event_state_1;                   // change state

         // we're done.  the handler for state 1 will execute the next time 
         // loop() is called.

         // This would be the place you could find an infamous goto within a 
         // switch blck, if timing needs to be suoer duper extra tight. 
         // It does happen sometimes, but rarely.
         return;
     }
 }

 void his_event_handler()
 {
     // this is the same logic, but with a different beat.
     // since these handlers do not block for timers or events
     // the handlers appear to run 'concurrently'
     switch (his_state)
     {
     case his_event_state_initial:
         // initialize our timestamp and go straight to state 1
         his_event_timestamp = (unsigned int)millis();
         his_state = his_event_state_1;

        // passing though to execute next state handler immediately

     case his_event_state_1:
         if ((unsigned int)millis() - his_event_timestamp < HIS_EVENT_TIMEOUT)
         {
             // not enough time has elapsed, nothing to do, so return
             return;
         }

         his_event_timestamp = (unsigned int)millis();  // get a time stamp
         his_state = his_event_state_2;                   // change state

        // passing though to execute next state handler immediately

     case his_event_state_2: 
         if ((unsigned int)millis() - his_event_timestamp < HIS_EVENT_TIMEOUT)
         {
             // not enough time has elapsed, nothing to do, so return
             return;
         }

         his_event_timestamp = (unsigned int)millis();  // get a time stamp
         his_state = his_event_state_1;                   // change state

         // we're done.  the handler for state 1 will execute the next time 
         // loop() is called.
         return;
     }
 }


void setup()
{
}

void loop() {

    // call our concurrent state machines
    my_event_handler();  
    his_event_handler();

   /* some other non-blocking code... */
}
```